# How do I rearrange this pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Right now, I have data for three poems. Each poem has 4 metrics (so columns A-D for the first poem, columns E-H for the second poem, columns I-L for the third). Each row contains scores from one person (so row 1 would contain person 1's scores for poems 1, 2 and 3, respectively, and row 2 would contain person 2's scores).

[Current format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoTMJ.png)
I want to reshape my dataframe so that there are only four columns (1 per metric), with the rows corresponding to each poem, like so: 
[Desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MToet.png)

Comment: Please, provide us with a [minimal reproducible example][1] and descrive what have you already tried to achieve your goal.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the source *df* has been created as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,25).reshape(2, -1),
    columns=[ 'Metric ' + x for x in list('ABCD') ] * 3)
```

so it contains:

```
   Metric A  Metric B  Metric C  Metric D  Metric A  Metric B  Metric C  Metric D  Metric A  Metric B  Metric C  Metric D
0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12
1        13        14        15        16        17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24
```

To convert it from "wide" to "long" format, you can run e.g.:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 4), columns=df.columns[0:4],
    index=[ 'Poem ' + x for x in list('123') ] * df.index.size)
```

getting:

```
        Metric A  Metric B  Metric C  Metric D
Poem 1         1         2         3         4
Poem 2         5         6         7         8
Poem 3         9        10        11        12
Poem 1        13        14        15        16
Poem 2        17        18        19        20
Poem 3        21        22        23        24
```

## Other solution

You can also do it also other way:

```
df.T.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['Poem ' + x for x in list('123')], df.columns[0:4]])).T\
   .stack(level=0).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```